# Using a Script to Hide a Row Dynamically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I would be very grateful for some help.

I have a script that will hide a row in my Google Sheet if the value "1" is entered in a cell in column A.

It works as expected.

It does not work, however, when I set the values of non-selected cells. (I want to change these using a formula). I can see that my primitive script is only assessing the value of the **current** cell.

Instead, I want to constantly evaluate all of the cells in the range A34:A97.

Any row that has a value of 1 in col. A should be hidden.
Any row that has a value <>1 in col. A should be unhidden.

Can anyone help?

Thank you,

Comment: Please add whatever code you have as an attempt, so we can see exactly what it is you're trying to do. @Cooper is correct that onEdit triggers will only fire when a user directly edits a cell. They don't fire when a script changes a value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So you're probably using an onEdit(e) function and that only works with user edits.  There is no trigger for edits that are performed by cell functions or other scripts.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)